# Send data URL string as an attachment in wp_email

Tags: attachments, wp-mail

We have a data URL string of PNG image file [here](http://jsfiddle.net/28nP4/) and we can pass it via AJAX to a PHP function via button click.

Now is it possible to convert it back as image file and add as an attachment to `wp_mail()`?

Comment: Yes it is. This could be helpful [PHP - get base64 img string decode and save as jpg (resulting empty image )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810501/php-get-base64-img-string-decode-and-save-as-jpg-resulting-empty-image).  If you save the image you can add it as attachment via the [wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) function.

Comment: We want send the file without saving it in server.

Comment: I link your question with my answer from StackOverflow "[Send Datauri string as attachment in wp_mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229092/send-datauri-string-as-attachment-in-wp-mail)". Maybe it helps others with the same problem..